# SAS global variable in IML

Tags: variables, sas, global

I want to create global variable in proc iml that specifies number of steps in another procedure:

```
%global iterations;

proc iml;
use data;
read all var _CHAR_ into data;
row = nrow(data);
%let iterations = row;
quit;

data _null_;
    do i=1 to &iterations;
    put i=;
end;
run;
```

But this way I finally get an error: "Invalid DO loop control information, either the INITIAL or TO expression is missing or the BY expression is missing, zero, or invalid". Even when I try to execute

```
%put &iterations;
```

I get

```
row
```

in response instead of the value corresponding to numer of rows of data table. Please advise me how to pass such information within procedures. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
call symput("iterations_glob", iterations);
```

in your `proc iml` after assigning the value to **row** variable like:

```
proc iml;
use data;
read all var _CHAR_ into data;
row = nrow(data);
iterations = row;
call symput("iterations_glob", iterations);
quit;
```

This new **iterations_glob** variable should be seen in data step.

Comment: works, but the second argument in call symput has to be a character value - I just used char(...) and it works, thanks!

Comment: The %let statement shouldn't be necessary here, you should just use `row` directly in the `call symput`.